# Number of features in a tree of Random Forest classifier-Python

Tags: python

I'm using Random forest classifier to classify a data set. I use python language.

```
RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200,oob_score=True,n_jobs=-1,random_state=101,max_features=None,min_samples_leaf=50)
```

I set `max_features=None`. So the individual tree takes all the features. But even though I set `max_feature` parameter, trees in random forest classifier doesn't use all the features.
How can find the number of features used in an individual tree?
or is there a default value for that?

Answer (score 0):

`max_features` is the *maximum* number of features that each tree can consider, not a guarantee that all of the features *will* be used.

If you want to see the individual trees, you can use the `estimators_` attribute. From the docs:

> estimators_ : list of DecisionTreeClassifier
>
> The collection of fitted sub-estimators.